# Postgresql INSERT triggers "0 row affected" workaround

Tags: postgresql, trigger, partitioning

In a INSERT trigger based table partition, insert always give "0 row affected". I think this problem is well know, it is even in the [todo](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Table_partitioning#INSERT).

Is there any workarounds for this issue in 9.4?

Comment: None I know of, which is a pity.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to catch the number of inserted rows using `GET DIAGNOSTICS` and then raise a notice/warning/whatever you prefer.  Here is a small illustration:

```
DO $$
    DECLARE cnt integer;
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO b SELECT i FROM generate_series(1,9) t(i);
        GET DIAGNOSTICS cnt := ROW_COUNT;
        RAISE WARNING '% row(s) affected', cnt;
    END; 
$$;
-- gives:

WARNING:  9 row(s) affected
DO
```

Comment: no, this won't work if `b` is a partitioned table.

Comment: @J-16SDiZ Sure.  If `b` is a partitioned table, there is possibly a trigger redirecting the `INSERT`s - this is what you state in your question, too.  This is an example for that trigger.  If `b` itself is a partitioned table, then you have subpartitions, which you should have mentioned in your question.  But then there must be a trigger on `b` to redirect `INSERT`s and so on...